# Deploy my symfony api rest app CORS errors

Tags: rest, symfony, hosting

I developped an application NUXTJS with a backend in Symfony. I deploy an API REST that allows me to talk beetween front and back. Everything work in local.

I want to deploy this on my host.
So I created two subdomains : one for my front and one for my backend.

So when I try to access to my application, I try to connect but I have these two errors CORS :

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://mysubdomain.domain.fr/api/login_check. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).**

And

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://mysubdomain.domain.fr/api/login_check. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).**

How can I fix this ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS by specifying the nextjs domain, not the api domain. If you want to be sure you can also allow all domain by using a `*`. But this reduces security a bit.

If you really want to be secure, you could add a proxy to your nextjs server, which proxies to your Symfony application. For example, in your NextJS application, proxy `/api` to the Symfony application hostname.
This way you don't need to enable CORS at all.

Comment: With * to allow all domain, it does not work so the problem isn't here.. When I deploy my Symfony did i do anything to launch the server ?

Answer (score -1):

If you use Api Platform you may need to configure the CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN variable in your .env file

Comment: yes I put this in my env file but It does not change anything...
###> nelmio/cors-bundle ###
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN='^https?://(mysubdomain.domain.fr)?$'
###< nelmio/cors-bundle ###